# Changing Woocommerce featured to vertical

Tags: woocommerce

I am wanting to change my featured products to be a vertical listing instead of horizontal. What I am looking for is

[image]

All I can find is how to edit the look but it still be horizontal.

Answer (score 0):

Disregard, I found the solution with a plugin